# How to restore dismissed reminders in Outlook 2010?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, reminder

How would I retrieve all the dismissed reminders in Outlook 2010?

Comment: It's a pity that Dismiss doesn't "do what you mean" and only dismiss the reminder once for a reoccurring reminder, rather than forever.

Comment: It's an old question admittedly but the solution is the second answer posted below (and should be accepted ;) )

Answer (score 25):

Your question asks to "retrieve all dismissed reminders".  I am not sure if, by "retrieve", you mean to view a list of all dismissed reminders or if you want to "undismiss" them.  I've been looking for a solution to the latter for a long time and just now stumbled upon it.  You first open the meeting or appointment (I double-click the event in my calendar).  At the top, you will see this:

[image]

If you dismissed the reminder then the Reminder field will say None.  Change it to a new interval and then click Save & Close.  You *should* get the reminder again.

Comment: You must also select a reminder that did not pass, otherwise it will go back to "none" after you save.

Answer (score 19):

It is not possible to restore already dismissed reminders.

But you can open the calendar view and [search by modification date](http://www.outlook-tips.net/outlook-2010/tip-209-finding-dismissed-reminders):

> In Outlook 2007 or Outlook 2010 use **modified:date** format in the search field.

For example, I would type `modified:2.10.2012` to see items I might have dismissed today

> It's not 100% accurate as many things can modify the item, but if you do this soon after dismissing the reminders, it should be 100% accurate.

Comment: I find it very hard to believe that Outlook 2010 has absolutely no way at all to restore an accidentally dismissed meeting reminder.

Comment: I use Outlook daily and would be happy to upvote your answer where you describe how to restore them

Comment: At least in outlook 2013 "today" is an acceptable value too, so to find dismissed calendar items you can search for "modified:today". Also works for tasks.

Comment: For some of us, `modified:8.22.2022` does not work, but `modified:8/22/2022` works.

Answer (score 0):

I accidentally dismissed some old reminders and the other answers didn't work for me for recovering them, so I restored a recent backup and reverted to that temporarily which brought them up.  If you don't have a backup, there's a possibility you can use the "Restore previous versions" option in the right-click menu of the PST file (or its parent folder) in Windows explorer to get a recent version.

To be safe, I closed Outlook, backed up my current PST, and disabled my network connection before restoring the old PST.

Answer (score 0):

If your reminders are from emails you can sort by date then flag status. You'll see all the emails with red flags. For each one add a new reminder.